# I`m wondering why it is being used the infinitive verb form with the 'to' in the folowing sentence

Tags: verbs, infinitives

He to show hundred earthquake victims the home.
I was questioned about the infinitive form 'to show' in this case and its usage. It sounds really a bit awkward, being not a native English speaker.

I would stress the sentence is a title of a news topic, so I can suppose that 'is' has been simply omitted, but not sure about that.

Please, advise if my guess is correct.

Comment: Yes, used in headlines often.  Prime Minister to visit Sweden.  (But, of course, not "He to visit Sweden.")

Comment: *He to show hundred earthquake victims the home* just looks like syntactic garbage to me, and I can't say adding ***is*** after ***he*** makes it any more grammatical OR comprehensible (which is to say if it's a newspaper headline it doesn't work very well, since I as a native speaker have no idea what it's supposed to mean).

Comment: As a headline, it doesn’t work at all. Not only is it completely ungrammatical (“He to show X” does not work, unlike “Prime Minister to show X”), a headline also cannot rely on conversational scope. Both “He” and “the home” only have meaning if the reader already knows what person and what home you’re talking about—and if this is the headline, there’s no way to know either. “Hundred earthquake victims” is also quite odd without an article. And the very situation is odd: in what context does anyone show a hundred earthquake victims a home? As @Fumble says, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Janus: I could go along with ***He** to replace **H** in airships because of safety concerns*.

Comment: Where did you see or hear this sentence?